# How does the Super Awesome Micro Project work?

Tags: motor, vehicle

I've recently read an article about a car which is made entirely of LEGO and it ***runs on air***. I'm curious about how it works. Can someone explain the details of it?

Here is the car:

[image]

These are all the details I have:

> Super Awesome Micro Project is: A car made of Lego, that drives, has
>   an engine made from Lego which runs on air. (wheels and some load
>   bearing elements are non-Lego)
>
> Super Awesome Micro Project Factoids
>
> - More than 500,000 LEGO pieces were used.
> - The car engine is made from standard Lego pieces and runs on air!
> - The engine has four orbital engines and a total of 256 pistons.
> - Top speed is not very fast, around 20-30km

Answer (score 6):

Assuming that you're asking about the engine in particular, it seems to be a large number of pneumatic engines that have been coupled together in order to supply the required torque. LEGO pneumatic engines typically consist of a pneumatic cylinder driving a crankshaft. Here's a basic picture to give you an idea:

[image: cylinder and crankshaft]

The shaft usually also controls a pneumatic valve that switches the direction of the piston to allow continuous rotation as shown here:

[image: valve control]

This allows the engine to run on air pressure being directed to the pneumatic valve without the use of any electrical components.

These images come from a fairly simple single cylinder pneumatic engine by nico71 [on Rebrickable](http://rebrickable.com/catalog/nico71/single-cylinder-engine) that includes [instructions](http://nicolas.lespour.free.fr/fichiers/images/Lego/Manipulateur/The_BI_LPE1_By_Nico71.pdf) if you are curious about more of the details of how these work, or if you would like to build your own.

Comment: Yes I'm talking about the engine. Is this working with electricity?

Comment: Air engine runs on compressed air. Or with a straw if you blow hard enough :)

Comment: This does technically run on air, but the air has to be compressed. This is often done using an electric compressor.